# How to decouple Authenticator Server and Resource Server in OAuth 2?

Tags: oauth

In my understanding, the Authenticator Server is in charge of Authenticate Code and Token, and the Resource Server need the Token to verify it.

So my solutions is that both them needs to connect the same OAuth database, or the Resource Server invoke the Authenticator Server to verify token, it seems they are coupled.

If I misunderstood something please correct me. 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct: the Resource Server and the Authorization Server need to "understand" each other and thus can be considered coupled. They typically live in the same administrative domain. OAuth 2.0 has not standardized the interface between RS and AS in the core spec meaning that the connection between the two is implementation specific. There is a more recent extension specification that standardizes the API between RS and AS, which would make it easier to use an RS and an AS from different vendors/stacks: https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7662

Answer (score 0):

As stated, you are correct. The OAuth 2.0 specifications do not describe how the Authorization Server and Resource Server interact.

UMA (User Managed Access) [defines interfaces between authorization servers and resource servers that, by default, enable centralized policy decision-making for improved service delivery, auditing, policy administration, and accountability, even in a very loosely coupled "public API" environment.](http://www.gluu.org/resources/documents/standards/uma/)

-jim